# Transferting large SQL Databases to Azure (>300MB)

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I want to transfer a local SQL Database to Microsoft Azure.
There are files stored in the db, so the db is about 300MB in size.

From SQL Server Management Studio I tried the following:

> Tasks->Generate Scripts

I was able to create the `.sql` script but couldn't load it.

I also tried the

> Tasks->Deploy Database to SQL Azure...

but after about 30 mins, it crashed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the Azure migration wizard instead of using SSMS create script.

[How to: Use the SQL Azure Migration Wizard](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-migration-wizard/)

Behind the scenes it uses bcp to transfer your data to Azure.

For the future, SSMS is not meant to handle large `.sql` files. Even a 1 or 2 MB file will crash SSMS. Instead you should use command line tools like [`sqlcmd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) or [`bcp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) - depending on your needs.

Comment: Very cool! My 300MB db was migrated in 18 minutes and 10 seconds. Thanks a lot